# Improving an 'each' statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, each

I am using Ruby on Rails 3 and I would like to improve the following code to a better way to do the same thing.

```
query = {}
params.each { |k,v| query[k.singularize] = v }
```

**How can I do that?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were actually finding that

```
params.each { |k,v| query[k.singularize] = v }
```

was taking too long, `singularize` would be taking up most of your time.

If most of the words were the same, I'd consider memoization.

Actually, if you had ten thousand parameters, I'd consider a code review!

Answer (score 1):

```
query = Hash[params.map{|k, v| [k.singularize, v]}]
```

Comment: It's still looping the data once and copying the values over.  I was also going to post basically this exact code but I don't think it's an improvement.  If anything it's harder to read.  Gonna run a benchmark between the two to see if there's a difference in performance.  Pending...

Comment: Eh he's missing a close bracket at the end, no biggie

Answer (score 1):

As nzifnab wrote, my other code seems to be slow. The following one may be slightly faster than the original posted.

```
query = params.each_with_object({}){|(k, v), h| h[k.singularize] = v}
```

Comment: I never knew about that method... turns out you can learn things on stackoverflow ;)  haha.  It's syntactically cool, but is logically identical to what he was doing originally kinda... I'll update mine w/ the benchmark.

Answer (score 0):

Well I had an idea (same idea as sawa) and decided I wanted to know if it was an improvement.  Here's the benchmark results:

```
params = {'puppies' => 'cute',
  'dinosaurs' => 'angry',
  'kittens' => 'kill them all',
  'wat' => 4}

Benchmark.bm do |x|
  x.report(".each"){10000.times{query = {}; params.each{ |k,v| query[k.singularize] = v }}}
  x.report("Hash"){10000.times{query = Hash[params.map{|k, v| [k.singularize, v]}]}}
end
```

And the result:

```
      user       system     total       real
.each 3.850000   0.390000   4.240000 (  4.260567)
Hash  3.910000   0.400000   4.310000 (  4.402304)
```

So very little difference, although Hash is the opposite of improvement, sadly - if performance was a concern for you.

I still tend to use the `Hash[]` format just because I like how `.map` works... but `.map` has to loop through every single item too so it's no different.

EDIT:

I went with the comment suggestion to do one really large hash instead of a tiny hash 10,000 times.  Here's the results:

```
myhash = {}
20000.times do |i|
  myhash[i.to_s * 2 + 's'] = i
end

Benchmark.bm do |x|
  x.report(".each"){query = {}; myhash.each{|k,v| query[k.singularize] = v}}
  x.report("Hash"){query = Hash[myhash.map{|k,v| [k.singularize, v]}]}
end
```

Results:

```
      user       system     total       real
.each 1.980000   0.110000   2.090000 (  2.100811)
Hash  2.040000   0.140000   2.180000 (  2.176588)
```

Edit 2:  Credit goes to sawa for this third method:

```
Benchmark.bm do |x|
  x.report(".each"){query = {}; myhash.each{|k,v| query[k.singularize] = v}}
  x.report("Hash"){query = Hash[myhash.map{|k,v| [k.singularize, v]}]}
  x.report("with_object"){query = myhash.each_with_object({}){|(k, v), h| h[k.singularize] = v}}
end

      user     system      total        real
.each  2.050000   0.110000   2.160000 (  2.174315)
Hash  2.070000   0.110000   2.180000 (  2.187600)
with_object  2.100000   0.110000   2.210000 (  2.207763)
```

If you (or someone) can find a way to modify each value in-place I suspect this would be the fastest way to do it:

```
params.each{|arr| arr[0].singularize!}
```

But you can't do that because

1. `singularize!` is not defined, and
2. when you try to do this:

```
params.each{|arr| arr[0].gsub!('s', '')}
```

You get an error:

```
TypeError: can't modify frozen string
```

I would just stick with the original version :p

Comment: Rather than do a small hash ten thousand times, try doing a large hash once?

Comment: What do you mean by "it has to loop through every item"? Don't you have to do it anyway?

Comment: @Mladen it would seem so.  We're tryin to find an improved way of doing it and I can't figure out one :)  So my answer to the question at this point is "Stick with the original version"

Comment: Try replacing `singularize` with `reverse` - I suspect it could be taking up the bulk of your time.

Comment: @Andrew It is, time dropped down to 0.038 on `.each` and 0.039 on `Hash`.  Relative results are still the same and his purpose is to singularize the string.  But it was a good thing to check anyway.

Comment: @nzifnab: Well, using functional approaches such as `each_with_object`, `inject` and `Hash[map]` are certainly more idiomatic (and arguably better) than using `each` and introducing superfluous local variable into the scope.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following in Ruby YARV 1.9.1, without ActiveSupport (hence `reverse` rather than `singularize`)

```
require "benchmark"

myhash = {}
2000000.times do |i|
  myhash[i.to_s * 2 + 's'] = i
end

Benchmark.bm do |x|
  x.report(".each"){query = {}; myhash.each{|k,v| query[k.reverse] = v}}
  x.report("Hash"){query = Hash[myhash.map{|k,v| [k.reverse, v]}]}
  puts RUBY_VERSION
  puts RUBY_ENGINE if defined?(RUBY_ENGINE)
end
```

gave me

```
      user       system     total       real
.each 6.350000   0.070000   6.420000 (  6.415588)
Hash  5.710000   0.100000   5.810000 (  5.795611)
1.9.1
ruby
```

So in my case, Hash was faster.

Considering the difference in speed between my benchmark and nzifnab's, I'd want to check the bulk of time wasn't spend on `singularize`.

**Update:**

Under 1.8.7:

```
      user        system    total       real
.each 11.640000   0.380000  12.020000 ( 12.019372)
Hash  15.010000   0.540000  15.550000 ( 15.552186)
1.8.7
```

So it's slower using Hash under 1.8?

Comment: I'm using Ruby 1.8.7 - my benchmarks had the two versions at about the same speed (using `.reverse`) -- I wonder if maybe the newer version or Ruby is faster using the Hash route.